# adding an hdri in blender 2.9?

Tags: versions, hdri

I know there is an option to add an hdri environment texture in the shader/node editor, but is this the only option in blender 2.9? only asking because I have not found an option to add one in the "world" tab.

Answer (score 3):

Just click the click the yellow dot next to the color picker and select *Environment Texture*.

[image]

[image]

Or from the shader editor select *World* instead of *Object*:

[image]