# Dark glass with weird imperfections

Tags: materials, lighting, glass

[image]I am following Blender Guru's donut & teacup tutorial and have gotten up to part 3 level 3 where I am starting to make my teacup transparent. After following all the steps in the video I am left with a glass material different from his. It is darker in some spots and has weird squiggly lines. Here are the render, material settings, and light path settings respectively.
Could somebody please help me fix this?

[image: Render]

[image: Material settings]

[image: Light path settings]

Above in the render, the dark parts I'm talking about are where it suddenly goes from pink to very dark pink. This is also where you can find the weird squiggly imperfections.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe it has to do with your topology?

Comment: could you please highlight the parts you're talking about? the handle has edge creases, to remove them, select all and Ctrl E > Edge Crease and in the Operator box, lower it down to 0

Comment: Yeah ok I'll edit the post including a photo that shows where I'm talking about

Comment: the squigglies are denoiser artifacts

Comment: Ok thanks, do you have any idea what could be causing the darkness?

Comment: Try an [HDRI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/193004/107598) for the lighting. You will get nice reflections and it brightens the darkness: https://i.stack.imgur.com/491mt.jpg

Answer (score 2):

*Edge Crease* makes the edges sharp when used with *Subdivision Surface*.

What I did was select a few edge loops in different places and <kbd>X</kbd> -> *Dissolve Edges*.  On most of the remaining geometry I removed the creases.

With the reduced geometry it's easier to place and rotate a few control loops and let *Subdivision Surface* fill in everything between.

[image]

[image]

If you turn *Clamping* -> *Indirect Light* and *Caustics* -> *Filter Glossy* to 0 it'll stop the glass from darkening your scene so much, but the scene will take some time to clean up the noise.  With the viewport denoiser on it looks like this at 128 samples.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you're an absolute legend. Now that I have fixed it could you please briefly explain what changing these lighting settings did, I'm a newbie to Blender and I want to fully understand every step I take. Thanks again.

Comment: I have an answer with some comparisons, but basically it's clamping the light being added to the scene when the ray passes through something. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219303/glass-casting-shadows-and-not-looking-real/219957#219957

Comment: @Matthew If this answer was helpful, be sure to upvote, and if it solved your problem to accept as well :)