# How to make an edge (or several edges) circle shaped?

Tags: modeling

We have an assignment to make a cup and my teacher made smooth circle shaped edges with only a few vertices in the instructions. However he did not explain how. I've tried with loop tools -> sphere, but that wasn't any help.

[image]

[image]

How do you achieve the result in the second image?

Comment: I don't speak swedish but "Proportional Editing" has got to be a hint :))

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/238405/110840 - check out this answer, observe how few polygons you actually need to define to achieve the goal

Comment: Try Loop Tools > Relax, that usually works pretty well for me.

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.

Comment: Hello and welcome. When posting here please avoid text inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be searched for or readily found in the future. It can't also be easily edited in case of errors or typos, nor updated when it gets outdated in case of future changes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's add a circle for example

[image]

[image]

Now go to `Modifier Properties` tab and select `Subdivision Surface`. Then increase `Levels Viewport`, for example, up to 3 and make sure you enabled this feature:

[image]

Now your mesh turned from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Use the same technique to make your handle smooth.

Comment: Just a thought. You may want to post an additional answer by starting with a torus and deleting part of the torus.  Then proportional edit perhaps.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger, I thought the question was not about how to make a perfect round handle (like a half of the torus) but how to make those edges between vertices to be curved in edit mode

Comment: Exactly. I just wanted to know how to make the edges curved. Proportional editing was just something we could play around with, but isn't very practical in this case. :)

That reminds me of something. Is there any way to modify the area of the proportional editing? It's very large by default and affects the whole cup with only one vertice selected.

Comment: @Alex Thank you very much for the illustrated explanation.

Comment: @Blendome, in order to modify proportional editing area, just scroll your mouse wheel up and down while moving your vertex