# How do you make a sky texture ignore shadows?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, shadows

I'm modeling an indoor scene where I need a skybox that lights up all of the objects even though it is indoors. Is there a way specifically to get a skybox texture in cycles that just lights up everything indiscriminately even if it would be in the shadow of something else? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding an hdri in blender 2.9?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193004/adding-an-hdri-in-blender-2-9)

Comment: Unfortunately in Cycles,, doing something like that would probably require you to render one layer with the "outer structure" removed, then another with just the outer structure, then composite them together. However, what many see as a deficit in EEVEE, is that is does just what you are looking for - HDRI's light objects regardless of whether or not their "view" of the HDRI is blocked (this includes "interior" areas) - perhaps you could use this to your advantage.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you want to use a skybox texture specifically?

They are most useful for either recreating on-site lighting (eg for VFX), in which case you don't need the walls modeled, or for reflections, where it would be odd to not include the wall.

Is there a reason for cycles not EEVEE? Generally you use cycles because you want more realistic light behavior.

Note: You do not necessarily need render passes - you can try unchecking the "shadows" option in the "ray visibility" section of the object properties for the walls.